# Sending email by using java code

Tags: java, jar, gmail

Good morning . I have a question . I want to send Email via Gmail by using eclipse oxygen.3 march 2018 . I used two jars : mail-1.4.7 and activation 1.1.1 . And I  allowed less secure access for my Gmail account . this is my code :

```
package Login_sys;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
public class EmailSend {
final String emailSMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
final String emailServerPort = "587";
String receiverEmail = null;
String emailSubject = null;
String emailBody = null;
String from = null ;
String password = null ;

public  EmailSend(String from,String password,String subject ,String message,String to)
{

    this.from = from ;
    this.password = password ; 
    this.emailSubject = subject ; 
    this.emailBody = message ;
    this.receiverEmail = to ;

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailSMTPserver);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", emailServerPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", emailServerPort);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

    try 
    {
          Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(emailBody);
            msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(receiverEmail));
            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("send successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending.!");
        }

    }

private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from , password);
    }
}}
```

I call it from other class :

```
 EmailSend f = new EmailSend ("******@gmail.com","*****","Testing","testin  
 email","****@gmail.com");
```

it always print : Error occurred while sending.! . I don't know where is my mistake

Comment: clarify your error. Attach stacktrace to question

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
 nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

You have set the wrong port number. Change it to:

```
final String emailServerPort = "465";
```

> Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
>
> Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465

Answer (score 0):

To fix the `SSLHandshakeException`, you need to update your `cacerts` in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`. Get a copy of `InstallCert.java`. Have a look here: [InstallCert.java](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target)

You can either place the `jssecacerts` under your `/lib/security` or use KeyStore Explorer and export the certificate from `jssecacerts` and import it to `cacerts`.